# Is it possible to inject a variable into route group which is common for all inside routes?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4, laravel-5.3

i have `categories` variable which basically gets all the data from `category table` and it is common for all the pages. So far i am injecting it to `view from the controller`.

I want to know is there anyway in the routes where i can specify the category and it will be available for all the routes inside that group rather then injecting it into view from controller ??

Something like this

```
 Route::group(['namespace' => 'Frontend'], function ($category = Category::all()) {
        Route::get('/', 'HomeController@welcome')->name('welcome');
        Route::get('/c/{slug}','HomeController@category')->name('frontend.category');
        .......
      ..........
    });
```

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update your `AppServiceProvider` as follow to have access to the `$categories` variable in all your views

```
public function boot()
{
    \View::composer('*', function ($view) {
        $categories = Category::all();
        $view->with('categories', $categories);
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your quick response. is it going to present all views or i can specify as well ??
like i have two type one is frontend and one is backend . can i make it available only for frontend??

Comment: My answer will give you access to the `categories` variable in all your views. You can read the docs to learn how to specify the view you want to send the variable to https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#view-composers

Comment: oh okay tyvm :)